# Why is the minimum value from an array always 0?

Tags: java, minimum

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] userInput = new int[8]; 
    int userDetermint,numEntered;

    Scanner csole = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Choose how many numbers you wanted to input the limits is up to 9: ");
    userDetermint = csole.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please Key In Your "+ userDetermint + " numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < userDetermint; i++ ){
        numEntered = csole.nextInt();
        userInput[i]= numEntered;
    } 
    int smallest = userInput[0];
    int largest = userInput[0];
    for ( int index = 0; index < userInput.length; index++ ){
        if(userInput[index]>largest)
            largest  = userInput[index];
        else if (userInput[index]< smallest)
            smallest = userInput[index];
    }
    System.out.println("Largest Number is "+ largest);
    System.out.println("Smallest Number is "+ smallest);
}

}
```

Was given an exercise by finding the maximum value and minimum values input by the user from 2- 10. I used array to pinpoint it but somehow the smallest values always return me 0. Wonder if someone could help me point out the mistake and explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
for ( int index = 0; index < userInput.length; index++ ){
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < userDetermint; i++ ){
```

or you will loop into the `0` area.